# CSV Changes by Python Script

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


a = [['Cliente', 'Fecha', 'Variables', 'Dia Previo', 'Mayor/Menor', 'Dia a Analizar', 'Analisis'],
['AAA', '27/12/2017', 'ECPM_medio', '0.41', 'Dentro del Margen', '0.35', 'Alerta'],
['AAA', '27/12/2017', 'Fill_rate', '2.25', 'Dentro del Margen', '2.7', 'Incremento'],
['AAA', '27/12/2017', 'Importe_a_pagar_a_medio', '62.4', 'Dentro del Margen', '61.21', 'Incremento'],
['AAA', '27/12/2017', 'Impresiones_exchange', '153927.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '173663.0', 'Incremento'],
['AAA', '27/12/2017', 'Subastas', '6827946.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '6431093.0', 'Incremento'],
['BBB', '27/12/2017', 'ECPM_medio', '1.06', 'Dentro del Margen', '1.06', 'Estable'],
['BBB', '27/12/2017', 'Fill_rate', '26.67', 'Dentro del Margen', '27.2', 'Estable'],
['BBB', '27/12/2017', 'Importe_a_pagar_a_medio', '11.34', 'Dentro del Margen', '12.77', 'Estable'],
['BBB', '27/12/2017', 'Impresiones_exchange', '10648.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '12099.0', 'Estable'],
['BBB', '27/12/2017', 'Subastas', '39930.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '44479.0', 'Estable'],
['AAA', '28/12/2017', 'ECPM_medio', '0.41', 'Dentro del Margen', '0.35', 'Estable'],
['AAA', '28/12/2017', 'Fill_rate', '2.25', 'Dentro del Margen', '2.7', 'Estable'],
['AAA', '28/12/2017', 'Importe_a_pagar_a_medio', '62.4', 'Dentro del Margen', '61.21', 'Estable'],
['AAA', '28/12/2017', 'Impresiones_exchange', '153927.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '173663.0', 'Estable'],
['AAA', '28/12/2017', 'Subastas', '6827946.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '6431093.0', 'Estable'],
['BBB', '28/12/2017', 'ECPM_medio', '1.06', 'Dentro del Margen', '1.06', 'Estable'],
['BBB', '28/12/2017', 'Fill_rate', '26.67', 'Dentro del Margen', '27.2', 'Estable'],
['BBB', '28/12/2017', 'Importe_a_pagar_a_medio', '11.34', 'Dentro del Margen', '12.77', 'Estable'],
['BBB', '28/12/2017', 'Impresiones_exchange', '10648.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '12099.0', 'Estable'],
['BBB', '28/12/2017', 'Subastas', '39930.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '44479.0', 'Estable']]


def status(group):
    condiciones = (np.array_equal(group, ("Estable", "Estable", "Estable", "Estable", "Estable")),
                   np.array_equal(group, ("Alerta", "Incremento", "Incremento", "Incremento", "Incremento")))
    resultados = ("Estable", "Crítico")
    return np.select(condiciones, resultados, default="Undetermined")

headers = a.pop(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=headers)
df1 = df.groupby(['Cliente', 'Fecha'])["Analisis"].aggregate([('Status', status)])
```

with my code I have this answer:

```
>>> df1
                     Status
Cliente Fecha              
AAA     27/12/2017  Crítico
        28/12/2017  Estable
BBB     27/12/2017  Estable
        28/12/2017  Estable
```

What I need is for my output to be the one I show but also add certain values ​​such as `Importe_a_pagar_a_medio` and `Subastadas`:

```
>>> df1

Cliente Fecha       Status  Importe a pagar   Subastadas      
AAA     27/12/2017  Crítico 61.21             6431093.0
        28/12/2017  Estable 61.21             6431093.0
BBB     27/12/2017  Estable 12.77             44479.0
        28/12/2017  Estable 12.77             44479.0
```

It is worth clarifying that I need to add the `Dia a Analizar` column which is the one that has the data that I show in the output that I am looking for.

Comment: Great, but how are those columns computed? Also, please don't add the python2.7 tag, your question is version independent.

Comment: Oh My apologies for that! I don´t know what are you asking about "computed" I'm a beginning on develop! @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: How do you calculate the values in Importe_a_pagar_a_medio and Subastada?

Comment: I have these values on my list! `['AAA', '27/12/2017', 'Importe_a_pagar_a_medio', '62.4', 'Dentro del Margen', '61.21', 'Incremento']`, `['AAA', '27/12/2017', 'Subastas', '6827946.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '6431093.0', 'Incremento']` @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ